# last-child not working properly with article

Tags: html, css

Why does article behave differently to div where last-child is concerned

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="example">111</div>
<div class="example">111</div>
<div class="example">111</div>
<div class="example">111</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent2">
<article class="example">111</div>
<article class="example">111</div>
<article class="example">111</div>
<article class="example">111</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent .example{ background-color: red;}
.parent .example:last-child{background-color: yellow;}

.parent2 .example{ background-color: red;}
.parent2 .example:last-child{background-color: yellow;}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/chLLa/1/

Comment: Because you're closing your article tags with div tags? Seems to work fine if you fix those typos. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/chLLa/2/

Comment: [Validators](http://validator.nu/) are your friend.

Comment: Ok - sorry ... actually I still have the problem in my actual code so I will try to rephrase it

Comment: got it .... turned out there was another element taking the spot of last-child that I hadn't noticed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing your tags properly

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="example">111</div>
<div class="example">111</div>
<div class="example">111</div>
<div class="example">111</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent2">
<article class="example">111</article>
<article class="example">111</article>
<article class="example">111</article>
<article class="example">111</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are closing your second set of `<article>`'s with `<div>`. In essence, you are closing your .parent2 div too early for the right last-child to work.

Also note, JSFiddle.net has a nice 'Tidy Up' feature that would have illustrated this.

Comment: must try that tidy up thanks